# How should I implement equality checking for classes that have objects of other classes as member?

Tags: c#, iequatable

I have a `Student` class that has an object of class `Name`.

At this point, the equality check of the `Student` class returns false, and I don't know why.

```cs
public class Student : IEquatable<Student>
{
  public Name Name { get; }

  public Student(Name name) => Name = name;

  public bool Equals(Student other)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
      return true;
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
      return false;

    return Name == (other.Name);
  }
}

public class Name : IEquatable<Name>
{
  public string First { get; }

  public Name(string first) => First = first;

  public bool Equals(Name other)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
      return true;
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
      return false;

    return First == other.First;
  }
}
```

```cs
var s1 = new Student(new Name("A"));
var s2 = new Student(new Name("A"));

Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2).ToString());
```

Of course, doing the equality check this way will return true.

```cs
var s1 = new Student(new Name("A"));
var s2 = s1;

Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2).ToString());
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(o1, o2)` instead of `==`. EqualityComparer tries to find best equality method for given class, while `==` just compares by reference if it's not overridden

Comment: @JL0PD That "best equality method" is _always_ `Equals()`, so need to whip out the default equality comparer, just call the method directly.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, overload for equals depends on whether type implements `IEquatable`. If type implements interface, then check will be done with `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other)`. If type doesn't implement interface, then `Object.Equals(object other)` is used. So it's not "always Equals"

Comment: you can use c# records,  they are much simpler and come with equality comparators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 (Recommended)**

Since you had implemented `IEquatable` interface for `Name` class, just calls `.Equals()` in `Student` class.

```cs
public class Student : IEquatable<Student>
{
    public Name Name { get; }

    public Student(Name name) => Name = name;
    public bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;
        return Name.Equals(other.Name); // Replaces with .Equals
    }
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle (Solution 1)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Az0ogY)

---

**Solution 2**

Or you need to implement [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) for the `==` and `!=` operators.

If you use `==` operator in:

```cs
public class Student : IEquatable<Student>
{
    ...

    public bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        ...

        return Name == (other.Name);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Name : IEquatable<Name>
{
    ...
    
    public static bool operator == (Name a, Name b)
    {
        return a.First == b.First;
    }
    
    public static bool operator != (Name a, Name b)
    {
        return a.First != b.First;
    }
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle (Solution 2)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vnKwBf)

Answer (score 3):

So, `==` by default for reference types just compares references. Implementing `IEquatable<T>` does not overload `==` automatically, you have to do it yourself. `string` does overload that operator, so it works in `Name`, but your `Name` class doesn't, so in `Student`, the default behaviour is used, which is equivalent to `ReferenceEquals()`.

Implementing `IEquatable<T>` correctly also means you need to override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`, which you don't do here.